# WooCommerce default redirection changes user-agent

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I am writing 2 themes for WordPress and WooCommerce. One is for the mobile only and another one is for PC. It works fine for normal links and the request can be defined by using `wp_is_mobile()` function to find out which theme to use.

The problem is that when the WooCommerce try to check out with empty cart, it will automatically redirect to cart. The `wp_is_mobile()` function will not get the right theme since the **user-Agent** will change from **Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone**.. to **Mozilla/5.0 (Windows**.

Do anyone know how to keep the redirection user-agent from the original request?

Comment: Does this also happen with other wordpress redirects?

Comment: Either: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/f434fc7d9a1f00363b07c60bde0aa3c0666e46ac/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L265 or https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8a22d416056af8b2e06dd4a464c5c8b69d466446/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L33 is responsible for the redirect

Comment: It happens to every redirections I thinks.

Comment: Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, It happens to every redirection from Wordpress.

Comment: AFAIK the wp_redirect function (used by woocommerce) only sets a location header, so it might be a problem caused the browser your are testing with.

Comment: Tested on both chrome and safari, doing the same thing.